# Is it possible to receive email bounce notifications for google app engine - python?

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, email-bounces

I have a google endpoints project using pure python, I use the inbuilt [mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail) to send emails. But for some reasons emails doesn't reach the receiver (quota is not exhausted). So I thought to create a bounce notifier. I  have done this so far.

app.yaml

```
inbound_services:
- mail_bounce
handlers:
- url: /_ah/bounce
  script: applications.APPLICATION
  login: admin
```

applications.py

```
from app.api.bounce.api import Bounce

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([Bounce])
```

bounce.py

```
import endpoints
import logging

from protorpc import remote, message_types

from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import BounceNotification
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import BounceNotificationHandler
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
from app.messages.auth import OutputAdminUserMessage


@endpoints.api(name='bounce', version='v1')
class Bounce(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, OutputAdminUserMessage,
                      path="bounce", http_method="POST",
                      name="bounce")
    def post(self, request):
        bounce = BounceNotification(request.POST)
        logging.info('Bounce original: %s', bounce.original)
        logging.info('Bounce notification: %s', bounce.notification)
```

And this doesn't seem to work this API isn't hit when I try to send an email to xyz@gmail.com. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for my own Question

You cannot setup this using a google appengine endpoint. I used webapp2 to setup this.

handle_bounced_email.py

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import BounceNotification
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import BounceNotificationHandler

class LogBounceHandler(BounceNotificationHandler):
    def receive(self, bounce_message):
        mail.send_mail(to='ajai@qburst.com', sender='ajai@qburst.com', subject='Bounced email',
                       body=str(self.request))
        logging.info('Received bounce post ... [%s]', self.request)
        logging.info('Bounce original: %s', bounce_message.original)
        logging.info('Bounce notification: %s', bounce_message.notification)

class BounceHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        bounce = BounceNotification(self.request.POST)
        logging.info('Bounce original: %s', bounce.original)
        logging.info('Bounce notification: %s', bounce.notification)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/bounce', LogBounceHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Now in app.yaml add a these

```
inbound_services:
- mail_bounce

- url: /_ah/bounce
  script: handle_bounced_email.app
  login: admin
```

`login:admin` allows only admin users to use this url